# Creating an AppIndicator using vala: Package `appindicator3-0.1' not found

Tags: indicator, vala

I am trying to create a Vala Application that will create an AppIndicator.

The problem is that when I compile my application I get the following error:

```
Package `appindicator3-0.1' not found in specified Vala API directories or GObject-Introspection GIR directories
```

I compile the application like so:

```
 valac --pkg appindicator3-0.1 --pkg gtk+-3.0 indicator.vala
```

I have libappindicator-dev installed and gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1 installed.

What I am missing?

Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to the [search on packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=bionic&arch=amd64&mode=filename&searchon=contents&keywords=appindicator3-0.1) you need to install related packages:

```
sudo apt install libappindicator3-dev gir1.2-appindicator3-0.1
```

Comment: Wow, I was sure I had  libappindicator3-dev already installed. It looks like not. Thanks ;)